# Why footprint dimensions are to edges and not centers

Tags: pcb-design, soldering, design, measurement, footprint

Whenever I'm looking at electronic components, I regularly see footprints with this kind of thing:

[image]

Dimension E seems to me to be somewhat unhelpful; rather than simply reading the centre distance (even something closer to C would be helpful, since it references the pad origin), I have to take E, then find X and subtract half of it. This isn't even close to the worst example; sometimes almost nothing references the origin and I have to chain 3 or 4 measurements together to figure out where to place something.

Why are pad layouts often given like this? My first thought is it could be for manufacturers rather than designers; knowing where the edge is makes more sense than knowing where the center is if one wishes to route out a shape.

Comment: Maybe there isn't enough room between the lines for the E and two arrowheads if it goes to the pad center ;)

Comment: I’m not sure this question is answerable, but it probably has more to do with the dimensioned drawings being produced by mechanical engineers rather than those familiar with EDA software.

Comment: In my experience, there is no consistency. Usually I don't have to create footprints but I often have to compare footprints to assess suitability as a second source. So many times I have had both footprints open and I am going back and forth and everything is dimensioned differently. One uses all edges the other uses all centers and width/height. Or, like this one, it is a mixed bag.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Perhaps even more to do with unskilled mechanical or EDA engineers.  My dad taught me decades ago when I was a wee bairn that everything is measured from a reference (and you use the largest tolerance) .  If you have to daisychain you have to add the tolerances.  In the above example there is no vertical reference unless you assume a midpoint.  A bad drawing from an inexperienced or careless designer.

Answer (score 2):

I have drawn many footprints/landpatterns i different ECAD tools.

How the recommended footprint dimensions are specified differs a lot between manufactures. Some have dimensions that can be used right away, others you have to calculate the dimensions you need to draw the footprint.

My guess would be, that some of the guys putting on the dimensions in the datasheet don't know how they are used by the PCB designer/layouter.

It's mostly a "problem" with special components that don't use standard footprints like connectors and modules.

Most ICs and passive components have the dimensions on the components specified in a similar way. Which makes it easy to apply the dimensions in a tool like PCB Library Expert, which will generate a footprint according to IPC recommendations based on the dimensions of the component.